# Why can't bash -c execute many commands in docker and k8s

Tags: bash, docker, kubernetes

I have a command to package my app.

```bash
cd /zq/app/aiforge; TAGS="bindata" make build
```

it can successfully packaged inside a container.

But when you execute it outside the container, many commands failed.

```bash
docker exec f2be0d6fa21c sh -c 'cd /zq/app/pengcheng/aiforge; TAGS="bindata" make build'
```

[docker exec failed image](https://i.328888.xyz/2023/03/21/Thq5v.png)

---

The same problem exists in k8s, since there is `sh` and `echo` in image `znai-xxx`
[k8s post start failed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btV7M.png)

---

Any ideas? It has been troubled for a long time, what does it have to do with bash and sh?

Comment: Looks like a `PATH` problem. What are the `PATH` values inside and outside the container?

Comment: Please add the error in plain text. Images are not readable and hard to be understood.

Comment: That sequence seems backwards to me – it looks like you're first trying to run your application, then build it.  Should the `make build` command be in a Dockerfile?  (Especially in Kubernetes I'd avoid `kubectl exec`: anything you do that way will get lost as soon as the container exits, it will only affect one replica of your Deployment, and sometimes the cluster can delete Pods without your involvement.)